# Textpad from Helios used for editing XML or HTML: How to identify closing / corresponding TAG?

Tags: html, xml, textpad

Working with Textpad as Editor on XML and HTML-files I'm looking for the possibility to identify the corresponding closing TAG. Ideal would be if the whole area between opening TAG and closing TAG could be marked or highlighted.

Hint: CTRL+M does not work (just jumps from > to < and vice versa).

The method should deal with following situations:

- Sometimes the TAG is closed by itself (with \>).
- Sometimes the same TAG is used within the TAG (like  in tree descriptions like jhm).

Comment: TP is an editor, not an XML parser.

Comment: See remark Sept, 23rd.

Comment: Please close the question, it is already answered (I do not have the rights for close votes).

Answer (score 0):

One part of the solution could be found in the help for macros - at least for marking a tag itself with its content, but not up to the closing tag. Because I'm working with textpad configured to use German as language of choice, I give a translation:

- Open "Search".
- Give "<" as to be searched.
- Start Makro Recorder.
- In Search Windows hit button "Next" (means next occurance of search string).
- Mark text until corresponding closing ">" using CTRL+SHIFT+M.
- End the Recording.
- Save Macro.

To step through the HTML-code you have to execute the macro.

Source: Help of TextPad 6.1.3 (32 bit).

Comment: After some time I think there is no solution because to achieve the behavior textpad would have to parse the XML.